# wget to display filename and percentage downloaded

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying to use `wget` in a `bash` and display a custom download percentage per file so that the user knows the process is running and what has been downloaded.  The below seems to download the files but there is no percentage or filename being downloaded displayed. I am not sure why and cannot seem to figure it out.  Thank you :).

**list**

```
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/FilterDuplicates.html
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/file1.bam
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/file2.bam
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/file1.vcf.gz
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/file2.vcf.gz
```

**bash that uses list to download all fiiles**

```
# download all from list
download() {
local url=$1
echo -n "    "
wget --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
echo " starting download"
}
cd "/home/user/Desktop/folder/subfolder"
wget -i /home/cmccabe/list --user=xxx--password=xxx --xxx \
xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/ 2>&1 -o wget.log | download
```

Comment: you're piping wget's output, so it detects it's in a non-interactive environment, and suppresses the progress bar. maybe try `--show-progres`, on the realization that whatever you're piping to `download` may also contain the progress bar characters

Comment: I tried `--show-progress` and that had the same result.  Thank you :).

Comment: When I run `wget --progress=dot` I don't see any percentages at all, just a column with amount transferred, 5 columns of dots, and a column of speeds.